# How to know which one fired eventListener

Tags: image, actionscript, loading, event-listener

I am loading images for a game before the game begin. So the main function sends links of images to an image loading object. This is what happen in my image loading object when I do image.load(link) in my main :

```
    public function charge(str:String, img_x:int, img_y:int, layer:Sprite):void
    {
        trace("load");
        urlRequest = new URLRequest(str);
        
        loaderArray[cptDemande] = new Loader();
        loaderArray[cptDemande].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loading_done);
        loaderArray[cptDemande].load(urlRequest);
        
        posX[cptDemande] = img_x;
        posY[cptDemande] = img_y;
        
        layerArray[cptDemande] = layer;
        
        cptDemande++;           
    }
```

The parameters img_x:int, img_y:int and layer:Sprite are related to displaying the images afterward. I am using arrays to be able to add the images to the stage when the loading is all done.

The event listener fire this function :

```
    public function loading_done(evt:Event):void
    {
        cptLoaded++;
        evt.currentTarget.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loading_done);
        if((cptDemande == cptLoaded) && (isDone == true))
        {
            afficher();
        }
    }
```

what I want is to be able to target the good loader to remove the event listener. What I am currently using(evt.currentTarget) doesn't work and generate an error code :

> ## 1069 Property data not found on flash.display.LoaderInfo and there is no default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracing `evt.currentTarget` shows that `currentTarget` is the `LoaderInfo` property. Try updating your code as follows:

```
public function loading_done(evt:Event):void
{
    cptLoaded++;

    // Current target IS the contentLoaderInfo
    evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loading_done);
    //evt.currentTarget.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loading_done);
    if((cptDemande == cptLoaded) && (isDone == true))
    {
        afficher();
    }
}
```

Just a wee tip for you while I'm at it, you could make life a lot easier for yourself by storing all the properties of your images on an `Object` and then pushing these onto a single `Array`, rather than managing a separate Array for each property.

Something like this:

```
    private var loadedImages:Array = new Array();       

    public function charge(str:String, img_x:int, img_y:int, layer:Sprite):void
    {   
        var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(str);

        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loading_done);
        loader.load(urlRequest);

        var imageData:Object = { };
        imageData.loader = loader;
        imageData.posX = img_x;
        imageData.posY = img_y;
        imageData.layer = layer;

        // Now we have a single Array with a separate element for 
        // each image representing all its properties
        loadedImages.push(imageData);

        cptDemande++;           
    }
```